# OpenSSL writing multiple memory BIOs to same sink BIO

Tags: cryptography, openssl

I am experimenting with OpenSSL under Objective C. I am trying to write SMIME asymmetric key encrypted data. I have no problem with opening a file, encrypting it and writing it to disk. I can encrypt a single memory buffer. What I want to do is implement a sort of scatter-gather approach with multiple memory buffers fed into the same encrypting BIO and written to disk serially.

My code is simple. I set up a cipher and get the public key/cert with `PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX()`. I push it on a `STACK_OF` X509s, `certs`, with `sk_X509_push(certs,...)`. I open my output file with `writeBIO=BIO_new_file()`. I create a memory BIO with `readBIO=BIO_new_mem_buf(buf,len);` and encrypt it with `p7=PKCS_encrypt(certs,readBIO,...);`. Finally I write it to the output with `i2d_PKCS7_bio(writeBIO,p7);` This works fine for just one memory buffer. If I try to pass multiple buffers in a loop, only the last is output. I have tried freeing and re-allocating the `readBIO` abd `p7` structured in between calls to `BIO_new_mem_buf` but this does not work.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE - I have a solution but not one I'm overjoyed about:

I have a wrapper for OpenSSL called AETPublicKeyWrapper

```
    @interface AETPublicKeyWrapper : NSObject
    {
    @private
       BIO *readBIO;
       BIO *writeBIO;
       STACK_OF(X509) *certs;
       const char *rmode,*wmode;
       PKCS7 *p7;
       EVP_PKEY *privateKey;
       const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
       int informat,outformat,flags;
    }

    ...
    -(BOOL)openInputFile:(const char*)fname;
    -(BOOL)openOutputFile:(const char*)fname;
    -(BOOL)openInputBuffer;
    -(int)writeToInputBuffer:(const void*)buf length:(unsigned long long)len;
    -(BOOL)loadPublicKeyCert:(const char*)certFileName;
    ...
    -(BOOL)encryptInput;
    -(BOOL)writeEncryptedOutput;
    -(BOOL)writeDecryptedOutput;
    ...
```

This encapsulates various OpenSSL API calls. `-(BOOL)openOutputFile:` for example is just

```
    -(BOOL)openOutputFile:(const char*)fname
    {
       if(!(writeBIO=BIO_new_file((char*)fname,"wb")))
          return NO;
       return YES;
    }
```

My encryption routine for multiple buffers into the same output looks like this:

```
    AETPublicKeyWrapper *owrapper=[[AETPublicKeyWrapper alloc] init];
    [owrapper loadPublicKeyCert:[keyPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]
    [owrapper openOutputFile:[saveAsPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]
    [owrapper openInputBuffer]
    /* fileData is a header */
    [owrapper writeToInputBuffer:[fileData bytes] length:[fileData length]]
    /* dirArray is an array of buffers */
    for(NSData *itemData in dirArray)
       [owrapper writeToInputBuffer:[itemData bytes] length:[itemData length]];
    [owrapper encryptInput]
    [owrapper writeEncryptedOutput]
    [owrapper flush]
    [owrapper release]
```

The various methods are (most error handling omitted; the casts are to shut the compiler up)

```
    -(BOOL)loadPublicKeyCert:(const char*)certFileName
    {
       X509 *x=NULL;
       BIO *newCert;
       certs=sk_X509_new_null();
       newCert=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
       BIO_read_filename(newCert,certFileName);
       x=PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(newCert,NULL,NULL,NULL);
       sk_X509_push(certs,x);
       return YES;
    }

    -(BOOL)openInputBuffer
    {
       if(!(readBIO=BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())))
          return NO;
       return YES;
    }

    -(int)writeToInputBuffer:(const void*)buf length:(unsigned long long)len
    {
       return BIO_write(readBIO,(void*)buf,(int)len);
    }

    -(BOOL)encryptInput
    {
       if(!(p7=PKCS7_encrypt(certs,readBIO,cipher,flags)))
          return NO;
       return YES;
    }

    -(BOOL)writeEncryptedOutput
    {
       if(i2d_PKCS7_bio(writeBIO,p7)<=0)
          return NO;
       return YES;
    }
```

This works, but my concern is that the input buffer could get arbitrarily large, so I would prefer to be able to write to the output and have it flush through with each write rather than accumulating and doing the whole encrypt/write thing at the end.

Comment: You best chance at getting answers is to show your code.

Comment: Hi David, and welcome. You should try and ask specific questions, not ask for opinions. Furthermore, if the above code contains an answer, it should be posted as an answer. Try to be as complete but sparse as possible, and do allow others to post answers before doing a complete overhaul.

Comment: Well, the comment above said 'show your code' so I did. As for my 'solution': this was the method I was using prior to asking this question. It works, but potentially impacts on the memory footprint of my app if I am gathering multiple files, the sum of whose sizes is large. For the time being I will keep my code as is, but if I ascertain a better solution I'll post it.